# Changing 'lamp' Colour Indicator within the Graphical User Interface (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I would like to change the colour within a single circular indicator within a Graphical User Interface, so that it shows when an action is completed or when it fails ['two tone green/red LED'].  I've looked through the inbuilt presets within the Toolbox but have been unable find anything.

I would therefore be grateful for any assistance.

[image: Successful Indication] [image: Failed Indication]

Comment: There isn't a control like that, but you can easily build one. Derive a custom class from Label, for example. Then paint the Circle in its `OnPaint` method. See `Graphics.FillEllipse()` (to fill the shape with a color) and `Graphics.DrawEllipse()` (to draw the border). Add a Public boolean Property (say, `IsActive`), where you call `Invaiidate()` to redraw the shape based on the value of the property (`True` = Color.Green, `False` = Color.Red). Maybe a couple of properties to define the color of when On/Off.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback . . . is it possible to use a RadioButton and to then change the colour within the 'dot'

Comment: With a custom control. See the [RadioButtonRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobuttonrenderer) class. The RadioButton is a specialized control, though. Drawing your own (with some support from the `[X]Renderer` classes, maybe) is much simpler in this case. Note that you could just use a standard Label + a Bitmap (the Label control supports Bitmaps very well).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.image?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

I've found this code on the msdn.microsoft.com forum, which changes the colour of the centre of the 'dot' when you press the RadioButton.

```
Private Sub RadioButton_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Paint, RadioButton2.Paint

     If DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
         e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, New RectangleF(2.5, 4.7, 7.2, 7.2))
     End If
```

So have incorporated it into my code, its not at all elegant and there is clearly room for improvement, but it does work.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.0.1") Then
        RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Green
        RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Else
        RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Paint
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.0.1") Then
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, New RectangleF(2.5, 4.7, 7.2, 7.2))
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, New RectangleF(2.5, 4.7, 7.2, 7.2))
    End If
End Sub
```

**Explanation**: when the 'Test Network' button is pressed it sends out a network ping, and depending upon the return the Network RadioButton 'dot' changes colour to either Green or Red,

[image: GUI With RadioButton and Button]

Comment: Well done. Keep improving it step by step. The Jimi's comments would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Here's ON/OFF LED control.

1. Add a new class to your project, name it say `OnOffLed.vb`, copy the code below and paste it in the new class.

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class OnOffLed
    Inherits Panel

    Public Enum LedState
        [On]
        Off
    End Enum

    Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer Or
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        UpdateStyles()
    End Sub

    Private _state As LedState = LedState.Off
    Public Property State As LedState
        Get
            Return _state
        End Get
        Set(value As LedState)
            _state = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _onText As String
    Public Property OnText As String
        Get
            Return _onText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _onText = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _offText As String
    Public Property OffText As String
        Get
            Return _offText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _offText = value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim rec As New Rectangle(2, 2, Height - 5, Height - 5)
        Dim recText As New Rectangle(Height + 2, 1, Width - (Height - 2), Height)

        Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics

        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        G.Clear(Parent.BackColor)

        If _state = LedState.On Then
            Dim cb As New ColorBlend With {
                .Colors = {Color.Green, Color.DarkGreen, Color.Green},
                .Positions = {0, 0.5, 1}
            }
            Using lgb As New LinearGradientBrush(rec, Color.Empty, Color.Empty, 90.0F) With {.InterpolationColors = cb}
                G.FillEllipse(lgb, rec)
            End Using
        Else
            Dim cb As New ColorBlend With {
                .Colors = {Color.Red, Color.DarkRed, Color.Red},
                .Positions = {0, 0.5, 1}
            }
            Using lgb As New LinearGradientBrush(rec, Color.Empty, Color.Empty, 90.0F) With {.InterpolationColors = cb}
                G.FillEllipse(lgb, rec)
            End Using
        End If

        G.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

        Using br As New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
            Using sf As New StringFormat With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}
                G.DrawString(If(_state = LedState.On, _onText, _offText), Font, br, recText, sf)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

2. Rebuild your project.
3. In the ToolBox under your project's component tab, you'll find the new control. OnOffLed. Drop it in your form as you drop any other control.

You can toggle the state through the `State` property, set different text if you need that for each state through the `OnText` and `OffText` properties.

Usage Example:

```vb
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.2.01") Then
        OnOffLed1.State = OnOffLed.LedState.On
    Else
        OnOffLed1.State = OnOffLed.LedState.Off
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for this . . .  unfortunately I’d only read it once I'd, having spent ages, writing my update below.  That’s quite a bit of code.  I do find it rather odd that so many, what I’d consider, from a novices point of view, basic features which by now should have been incorporated into Visual Studio !

Comment: JQSoft, Thank you very much for this and it works perfectly, I really appreciate it . . . I would be grateful for your comment on my rather cack-handed adaptation of a script I found on the Microsoft Forum.